os.mkdir(directory,title) TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
I'm trying to make a directory but I keep getting the error
File "c:\Users\Isaac\OneDrive\Desktop\Python\testing.py", line 5, in <module>
    os.mkdir(directory,title)
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

my code is
directory = r"C:\Python"
title = "hi"
os.mkdir(directory,title)

I tried changing it to os.makedirs() but that didn't work, and I tried using strings instead of variable

I think you are using the second argument incorrectly.

your error tells you the problem, the function os.makedir expects an integer as it's second input value, for the optional mode parameter.  As 'hi' is not an integer it throws this error.
I suspect you want to create a folder called hi in your directory.  In which case you need to join together your directory and name into one file path string to input into makedir, like this:
directory = r"C:\Python\hi"
os.mkdir(directory)

